# Centering image in button producing unexpected results

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to center an image inside a `UIButton` and it's producing unexpected results.

(1) When I print the center points of the button and the image in the console, they don't match up, but they should, shouldn't they?

(2) When I change `.center` to anything else, like `.left`, the image still remains in the center. `.center` appears to have no effect.

```
func addSearchButton() {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame.size.width = 56
    button.frame.size.height = 56
    button.frame.origin.y = 20 + 8
    button.frame.origin.x = 8
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .center
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "searchIcon"), for: .normal)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "searchIcon"), for: .highlighted)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSearch), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
    print("search: \(button.center.x)")
    print("search: \(button.imageView!.center.x)")

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Of course, they don't match up because they have different superviews. (view vs button)??

(2) Seems like you are expecting layout alignment. UIImageView's contentMode usually has different effects depending on its frame size and image size. If you want change the image position, update imageEdgeInsets instead.

Comment: Fair point on (1) LOL. So my use of `button.imageView?.contentMode = .center` in this example is incorrect? The only way to position an image to the left or the right inside a button is manually with insets?